# Help with handling json response

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I am still trying to figure out how to use json.. can someone please help me understand how to deal with this response.  My query is :

```
$.ajax({
url: s7query,
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function(){
// how do I deal with the response?
} 
});
```

The json I am querying returns (with either a 1 or 0):

```
s7jsonResponse(
{"catalogRecord.exists":"1"},"");
```

All I need from this is the number and put that into a variable so I can then run conditional logic against that result.  Thanks for any help understanding this...

If I try and handle the success with any function firebug just returns that s7jsonResponse is not defined.  I tried to define it as a variable outside of the request.  Now I see in firebug it is returning the json from all the requests, however it is returning them as errors and now says s7jsonResponse is not a function.  I think I am close.. please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I missed the json`p` part! All you need is to define a method for s7jsonResponse.

```
function s7jsonResponse (jsonData, someString) {
    alert(jsonData["catalogRecord.exists"]);
    // deal with the response here
}
```

[See this for details on JSONP](http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/)

**initial response**

<strike>I noticed that `catalogRecord.exists`, this has a `.` in it and it won't extract. If you don't have a strong reason to do so, you could change it to `catalogRecordExists` and use below solution.</strike>

```
$.ajax({ 
url: s7query, 
dataType: 'json', //removed jsonp in the last edit
success: function(data){ // this is the method that executes on success
            // parseJSON is not required as you already put it in dataType
            // alert(($.parseJSON(data))["catalogRecord.exists"]); 
            alert(data["catalogRecord.exists"]);
         }
});
```

**Note**:
The data that you send back should = `{"catalogRecord.exists":"1"}`

You can use [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to do the same(it internally calls `$.ajax`)

Comment: Thanks... but this still throws errors that s7jsonResponse is not defined

Comment: the response will be in variable `data`

Comment: So that's the error: `s7jsonResponse is not defined`. Show us the function `s7jsonResponse`.

Comment: That does not make any sense to me.. the json that is returned is in my question, it is wrapped in s7jsonResponse and that is where I am having troubles. I tried declaring s7jsonResponse as a variable outside of the request... now I get the right data back... sort of but I only see it in my firebug inspector where it returns as errors saying s7jsonResponse is not a function =(

Comment: `s7jsonResponse( {"catalogRecord.exists":"1"},"");` is not a valid JSON format. This is a function call where you are calling `s7jsonResponse();` with arguements `{"catalogRecord.exists":"1"}` and `""` where the first one doesn't make sense.

Comment: unfortunately i have no control over the json response... I am just trying to handle the data it gives me.  I am surprised to hear it is not valid as this is something provided by adobe and used by tons of big timey websites.

Comment: Could you provide the exact response from adobe?

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying jsonp as the dataType in your ajax call.  That tells the web service to return a jsonp response, not a pure json response.  So, given the response you are getting, you should define a function named s7jsonResponse that takes two arguments.  The first should be a json object, and you'll have to look at the api to get the second because it's empty in the example you give us.

In your s7jsonResponse method, you can then look at the data that is returned, but as Lobo points out, you have the dot in the name.  Because of that, you will have to access the property using bracket notation.  Something like:

```
function s7jsonResponse( obj, nothing )
{
    var exists = obj["catalogRecord.exists"];
    // do your stuff with your 1 or 0 which is stored in exists
}
```